# document visibilitychange event when visibility changes programmatically

Tags: javascript

I minimized my real world case to a tiny example.

What I want to achieve is to catch document visibility change event.

I see that it works, when I change visibility by switching between browser tabs, but when I change visibility programmatically it does not work.

And by the way, I really need to deal with visibility event.

In my real world case visibility is changed by some external framework (when switching between html tabs).

I'm not able to catch tab clicks, because tabs may be nested.

So, the only thing that I need is document visibility event.

Here is a minimized code, in case demo is not available

```
<button onclick="hideIt()">Hide</button>
<iframe id="one"></iframe>
<script>
    var doc = document.getElementById('one').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>'+
    'One.' +
    '</body></html>');

    doc.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
        console.log('hidden:' + doc.hidden,
                    'state:' + doc.visibilityState)
    }, false);

    doc.close();

    function hideIt() {
         var iframe1 = document.getElementById("one");
         iframe1.style.display = "none";
         //iframe is not visible and its internal document as well, but
         //visibilitychange event is not fired
    }
</script>
```

So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#sec-visibilitychange-event

> The User Agent MUST fire the visibilitychange event at the Document
>   *when the User Agent determines* that the visibility of the Document
>   contained by the **top level browsing context** has changed.

The iframe is not a top level browsing context and thus the event is not fired. Furthermore the event is only fired when the User Agent determines it should. This table lists many actions which trigger the event: [image]

https://github.com/w3c/page-visibility/issues/18#issuecomment-154187852

There is no solution to the problem if you need to only deal with the visibilitychange event. However, by binding the button-click and the visibilitychange event to the same function, the same end goal could be achieved. For example:

```html
<button onclick="hideIt()">Hide</button>
<iframe id="one"></iframe>
<script>
    var doc = document.getElementById('one').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>'+
    'One.' +
    '</body></html>');

    function visibilityChange() {
      console.log('hidden:' + doc.hidden,
                  'state:' + doc.visibilityState)
    }
    doc.addEventListener('visibilitychange', visibilityChange, false);
    doc.close();

    function hideIt() {
      var iframe1 = document.getElementById("one");
      iframe1.style.display = "none";
      visibilityChange();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Unfortunatelly, I'm not able to do it like so, because, in my real case, this hiding is done by framework. Imagine, that I have a window with two nested tabpanels and each tabpanel has a number of tabs. My iframe is in the innermost tab and so it can be shown or hidden by activating dozens of tabs in each tabpanel. Indeed, it's impossible to bind one and the same function to all these tabs. At least, it would be an ugly solution,